# How to extend neighbor function to 24 using code from Moore and Von Nuemman example

Tags: netlogo

I am learning how to use net logo and one of the things I am trying to do is to create a larger neighborhood then the built in 8 that comes with the agent set "neighbor".

I want to use this extended neighborhood to run Conway's Game of Life with more neighbors.

I have used the built in function from the Game of Life available in the netlogo's model library.

```
to go


  let neighbors24 [list pxcor pycor] of patches with [abs pxcor <= 2 and abs pycor <= 2]


  ask patches
    [ set live-neighbors count neighbors24 with [living?] ]
  ;; Starting a new "ask patches" here ensures that all the patches
  ;; finish executing the first ask before any of them start executing
  ;; the second ask.  This keeps all the patches in synch with each other,
  ;; so the births and deaths at each generation all happen in lockstep.
  ask patches
    [ ifelse live-neighbors = 3
      [ cell-birth ]
      [ if live-neighbors != 2
        [ cell-death ] ] ]
  tick
end
```

I expect neighbors24 to increase the number of neighboring cells from 8 to 24, instead I am met with the following error.

"WITH expected input to be an agentset but got the list [[-2 -1] [0 0] [2 2] [-2 2] [-1 1] [2 -2] [0 2] [-1 -1] [-2 1] [-1 -2] [2 1] [1 0] [-1 0] [-1 2] [1 -1] [0 -1] [-2 0] [0 -2] [1 2] [-2 -2] [1 -2] [0 1] [2 0] [2 -1] [1 1]] instead."

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by using the built in function - there are several Game of Life examples in the library, and none have an extended neighbourhood procedure. However, the 'Moore & Von Neumann Example' in the library does what you want.

Comment: I went to the Moore & Von Neumann section and attempted to use the to-report Moore-offsets section as my method for extending the game of life neighborhood. I'm guessing from your comments that this was not the best method of doing so.

Comment: should have worked. Can you do a new question with your code as it is and a description of the problem? The point of doing it this way is that you can get the neighbourhood around any patch (instead of around the origin as you have)

Comment: I submitted it as a new question with all my code and how I have it set up. My thinking was that it would check around every live patch, but I do not think it is doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetLogo should tell you which line is giving you the error. Please include that in your future questions.

In this case, the error is (presumably) the line `set live-neighbors count neighbors24 with [living?]`. Your problem is that `with` selects those agents in the specified agentset that meet a condition. So `patches with [pcolor = yellow]` would get the yellow patches. However, neighbors24 is not an agentset, it's a list of patch coordinates.

It is a common NetLogo novice mistake to create lists, particularly if you have experience with other programming languages. If you are creating lists of agent identifiers (eg coordinates for patches, or `who` numbers for turtles) you almost certainly want an agentset instead.

The modified line `let neighbors24 patches with [abs pxcor <= 2 and abs pycor <= 2]` will create neighbors24 as an agentset.

Comment: In this case, I think it's necessary to compute the `neighbors24` with each patch instead of just once for all patches?

Comment: Yes, but that's not the question asked, and there are other design problems in the model. So I focused on answering the question about the error and left a comment on the question pointing to the more appropriate way to do extended neighbours.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added the code that you said and while it compiles correctly, I do not think it is working as intended. I tested this out by placing a 3 live cells within the 24 cell perimeter on a blank canvas and it still resulted in dead cells.

Comment: StackOverflow requires you to ask a new question if you have a new question. That way you will need to describe exactly the problem (eg error message, what you expect compared to what you got) and the relevant code. But check out the code I pointed to in my comment on your question and see if that helps.